# Numba kernel is not allowing dictionaries or string functions

Tags: python, string, dictionary, cuda, numba

I am trying to pass a dictionary to a Numba CUDA kernel as well as perform various string manipulations in the kernel (such as `string.split()`). Neither of these are working.

I am using numba version 0.44.1. According to the release notes (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/release-notes.html), both dictionaries and string.split() are supported by Numba, so I am not sure why neither work.

Code for dictionary:

```
from numba import cuda


aDict = {'potato':7,'Achashveirosh':127,'GzeiraShava':613,'KimLeiBidiRabbaMinei':4}

@cuda.jit
def kernel_thing(chashuvDict):
   print(chashuvDict['GzeiraShava'])

kernel_thing[128,30](aDict)
```

Code for string.split():

```
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit
def kernel2():
    eggs = "hello"
    eggs.split('e')

kernel2[128,30]()
```

For the dictionary I get the following error:

> line 34, in typeof
>       raise ValueError(msg)
>
> ValueError: cannot determine Numba type of < class 'dict'>

For the `string.split()`, I also get an error:

> No definition for lowering (unicode_type, unicode_type, omitted(default=-1)) -> list(unicode_type)
>
> File "testKernel2.py", line 6:
>
> eggs.split('e')

Comment: is KimLeiBidiRabbaMinei derived from kidei rishato or lo yihiye ason? That could be causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to pass a dictionary to a Numba CUDA kernel as well as perform various string manipulations in the kernel (such as string.split()). Neither of these are working.

The are not working because neither strings nor dictionaries are supported in Numba GPU kernels (see [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html))